# Find unmapped fields in database DDL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ddl

Our schema that is mapped by Hibernate is evolving over time and we are using flyway to migrate between different versions; it works great. We then automatically do a migration on a copy of our database during our CI-build pipeline and start hibernate to verify that our model is compatible with our schema, thus making sure that the migration will work when deploying.

There is however one issue if we forget to remove a field in the database, but remove it in the model. The problem gets worse if that fields is a *NOT NULL* field or a foreign key.

I would therefore like to build a check during startup that verifies that the database **does not contain any fields that are unknown to hibernate**. Hibernates *SchemaValidator* checks that no fields are missing in the database, but does not care for the vise versa.

Any ideas how I might write this logic. I was thinking that I might *SchemaValidator* to get the DDL, but there seem to be many pitfalls to take care of.

Comment: I always put the keyword 'Custom' when I do a dependency injection search in google. In this case "hibernate CustomSchemaValidator" i.e. https://gist.github.com/jelies/8951881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Generate a new schema from Hibernate (hbm2dd) to a separate database schema/user/owner. Let's name it `HIBERNATE_SCHEMA`.

2) Query the database dictionary/metadata for the differences between the original (let's name it `ORIGINAL_SCHEMA`) and the hibernate schema. For example, in Oracle:

```
select table_name, column_name from ALL_TAB_COLS
where owner = 'ORIGINAL_SCHEMA' 
and (table_name, column_name) not in
  (select table_name, column_name from ALL_TAB_COLS where owner = 'HIBERNATE_SCHEMA');
```

The result of the above query will give you all the columns that exist in the ORIGINAL_SCHEMA which don't exist in the HIBERNATE_SCHEMA.

Comment: Clever method. I won't be able to do it this way though as some on the DDL is not the same as what hibernate would generate. e.g. foreign key names. Updating the model might be the only way, but it will be quite a task, so other suggestions are very much welcome :)

Comment: I've not been able to come up with a better solution than yours - and I've realized a few nice side effects of having a model that is 100% annotated. We will therefore proceed by annotating the rest of the model (mainly indices and foreign key names has to be set).